# Code structure revealing function locations in file system

Tags: python, windows, file, python-3.x, directory

[A general question not specifically related to pywin32.]

I've just starting using pywin32 to learn to interact with outlook 2010.  One line of code is such:

```
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Now, when I look in Python33 directory I see a file called win32com; that's fine.  When I go into win32com directory I see a file called client; that's fine.  When I go into client directory however there is no file called Dispatch.  This is because Dispatch is a function within **_*init*_**.  Now, in such instances how am I to find where this .GetNamespace function is, it appears to my knowledge that the above code doesn't give me any clues, but does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  code is part of  Windows. Dispatch creates an application object, which is defined by Windows and not in the Python code. The documentation for this method and the Application object is below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865800.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221371(v=office.11).aspx